# MySQL counting large table based on sameness of entries

Tags: mysql

I have a table something like this:

```
Key .  ClerkID . CustomerID .  ProductCode .  Date          Type .   Color
1      1010      123           AAA            2018-01-01 .  1 .      Red
2      1010      123           BBB            2018-01-01 .  2 .      Blue
3      1010      123           AAA            2018-01-02 .  1        Red
4      1010      456           CCC            2018-01-01 .  1 .      Red
5 .    1010      456           DDD            2018-01-02 .  2        Red
6      1010      456           DDD            2018-01-02 .  3        Blue
7      11 .      456           AAA            2018-01-02 .  3        Blue
```

it's about 300,000 entires. I'm trying to run a query that counts multiple products ordered by the same customer, same clerk and on the same date.

So it'd report a table like this:

```
Products .    Count
AAA .         2
AAA, BBB      1
CCC, DDD      1
DDD           1
```

in reality, i actually to ignore any entry that is only a single product:

```
Products .    Count
AAA, BBB      1
CCC, DDD      1
```

EDIT: here is a FIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ceb55/3

and the final table would be:
Clerks 1010, 1030; Products: AAA, BBB, CCC; cnt: 3
Clerks 1010, 1020; Products: AAA, BBB; cnt: 2
Clerks: 1010, 1020, 1030; Products: AAA; cnt: 3

and actually ignoring the last line would work

OR an even easier to read fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7252
where the goal would be:
Clerks: Carl, Bob, Dave; Products: AAA, BBB, CCC; cnt:4
...

Comment: here is an sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ceb55/3

Comment: for anyone stumbling: here is a working fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7252/12

Comment: and code `SELECT Products, group_concat(distinct ClerkID), COUNT(PRODUCTS) as cnt FROM (SELECT 
ClerkID, 
CustomerID, 
Date, 
group_concat(distinct ProductCode) AS Products, 
count(distinct ProductCode) AS cnt

from Table1
group by 
ClerkID, 
CustomerID, 
Date
HAVING cnt > 1) t GROUP BY Products`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that counts different products ordered by the same customer, same clerk and on the same date,  and ignores the products that only appear once, is the following one (ignoring the type and color here, although there could be many types and colors for a single product code, according to your data):

```
SELECT
ClerkID,
CustomerID,
Date,
ProductCode,
COUNT ( * ) as cnt 
FROM <your table name>
GROUP BY
ClerkID,
CustomerID,
Date,
ProductCode 
HAVING cnt > 1
;
```

Comment: sort of but this doesnt report the list of product codes, only 1 product code per count. a note, i had to change "COUNT ( * )" to be "COUNT(*)". i wasnt familiar enough to know

Comment: your requirement is a bit unclear, could you elaborate a little bit more, if possible

Comment: so changed `ProductCode` to: `group_concat(ProductCode separator ', ') ProductCode`

Comment: oh wait, no that doesnt do it. it just lists the same productcode repeatedly

Comment: as far as I understood, you would like to group products by comma separator, based on `ClerkID`, `CustomerID`, `Date` and total count? is that right?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. it looks like it works if also remove `ProductCode` from the `GROUP BY`. yes, i was trying to get the products all comma separated

Comment: for example, `clerkID1, customerID1, 20180530, AAA, 3` and `clerkID1, customerID1, 20180530, BBB, 3` could be grouped into `clerkID1, customerID1, 20180530, {AAA,BBB} 3`

Comment: however for example, `clerkID1, customerID1, 20180530, AAA, 3` and `clerkID1, customerID1, 20180530, BBB, 2` could not be grouped because the counts are different. is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172030/discussion-between-kidnim-and-mangusta).